# Hyperledger fabric Private key using Fabric-CA -server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am new to Hyperledger fabric, i am using the hyperledger fabric ca server to register the admin,user,peer. I have few doubts

```
 1. when i create the admin, using fabric-ca-client start --id admin:adminpw its create the config file and msp folder in home directory, does msp contain the private key of admin.

 2. if msp contain the private key, when we host the fabric-server into live do we still keep the msp folder in live/production,does the private key will be exposed. how its works.
```

Please it would be helpful someone clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) When you use fabric-ca-client to enroll ( `fabric-ca-client enroll` ), it will create the private key in the `map/keystore` directory.

2) If you do not want to expose the private key on the filesystem, you can store the private key in an HSM (Hardware Security Module) using via PKCS11.  See https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html?highlight=pkcs11#hsm for more details.  If you don't have access to an HSM, then you should minimally encrypt the file system (if running in a cloud) and ensure that you set the file permissions to `0400` for the user you use to start your fabric processes.

Comment: thank you !, if i am using the fabric ca serve in cloud, it will keep the copy of certificate and even the private key of user ?

Comment: fabric-ca-server does not keep the private keys for clients ... it only signs and stores the public keys.  the private keys for clients are stored wherever you run the fabric-ca-client